# NameError - wrong constant name when creating user (Devise, Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-activerecord

I'm using Rails 5.0.5 with Devise 4.3.0 for authentication. This app has been running smoothly for months, until I added a 'type'=>'string' attribute to my User model and attempted to create a new user. Submitting the form gives me a 500 internal server error. In this example, the User.type = 'hunter'.

```
 NameError - wrong constant name hunter:

 activesupport (5.0.5) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `const_get'
  activesupport (5.0.5) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (5.0.5) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `each'
  activesupport (5.0.5) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `inject'
  activesupport (5.0.5) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `constantize'
  activesupport (5.0.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:583:in `get'
  activesupport (5.0.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:614:in `constantize'
  activerecord (5.0.5) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:177:in `find_sti_class'
  activerecord (5.0.5) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:209:in `subclass_from_attributes'
  activerecord (5.0.5) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:55:in `new'
  devise (4.3.0) lib/devise/models/registerable.rb:20:in `new_with_session'
  app/models/user.rb:58:in `new_with_session'
```

user.rb:

```
def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    if session['devise.user_attributes']
      new(session['devise.user_attributes']) do |user|
        user.attributes = params
        user.valid?
      end
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

Is Rails think this attribute value is a ClassName?? Can't seem to figure this one out. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveRecord uses the `type` column for Single Table Inheritance (STI) by default and the `type` value is expected to name a class. Presumably you don't have a `hunter` class so you get a confusing `NameError` from deep inside the guts of ActiveRecord.

From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-inheritance_column):

> **inheritance_column()**
>   Defines the name of the table column which will store the class name on single-table inheritance situations.
>
> The default inheritance column name is `type`, which means it's a reserved word inside Active Record. To be able to use single-table inheritance with another column name, or to use the column `type` in your own model for something else, you can set `inheritance_column`:
>
> ```
> self.inheritance_column = 'zoink'
> ```

Either rename your `type` column to something else or tell ActiveRecord to use some other column name for STI:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = 'there_is_no_sti_here' # Or whatever you're not using for a column name.
end
```

Using `self.inheritance_column = nil` also works.

---

If you're doing this a lot then you could make it declarative by adding a concern:

```
module STISuppression
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    self.inheritance_column = nil
  end
end
```

and then say things like:

```
class SomeModel < ApplicationRecord
  include STISuppression
end
```

Same effect but it makes it clear what you're up to.